# Проблема с TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, activity-life-cycle

Моя программа считывает данные из файла и отображает их в `TextView`. Мне нужно определить количество виртуальных страниц, на которые разбивается текст файла. Высота/ширина одной страницы = высоте/ширине всего экрана. Алгоритм, как посчитать, я разработал. Вот код:

```
countOfLines = (text.getHeight() / text.getLineHeight());
pages = Math.round(text.getLineCount() / countOfLines) + 1;
pagesView.setText(currentPage + "/" + pages);
```

`text` - `TextView` с текстом.
`countOfLines` - кол-во страниц.
`pagesView` - `TextView` в котором отображается кол-во страниц.

Итак, проблема заключается в том, мне нужно определять количество страниц сразу после отображения содержимого, но когда я пытаюсь выполнить этот код в любом из методов жизненного цикла, `text.getHeight()` всегда возвращает 0. Но за пределами методов жизненного цикла приложение возвращает корректное значение. Так как мне быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во время вызова методов активити `onCreate(...)`, `onStart()` и `onResume()` виджеты еще не отрисованы на экране, поэтому, в частности, метод `getHeight()` возвращает ноль.

Стоит обратить внимание на то, что если Вы откроете активити, затем свернете приложение и снова вернетесь в него (при условии, что активити не была уничтожена), в коллбэках `onStart()` и `onResume()` метод `getHeight()` виджета вернет корректное значение.

Корректные размеры виджета можно получить после его отрисовки. Поймать событие окончания отрисовки (в частности его) можно с помощью установки `OnGlobalLayoutListener` объекта `ViewTreeObserver` соответствующего виджета и реализации метода `onGlobalLayout()`:

```
mTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int textViewHeight = mTextView.getHeight();
    }
});
```

После получения результата не забудьте удалить установленный `OnGlobalLayoutListener` (так как метод `onGlobalLayout()` будет вызываться при каждой перерисовке `view`).

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вы пытаетесь получить высоту в `onCreate()`? Дело в том, что пока этот метод не выполнится `View` не получат размерность. Получить высоту вы сможете только после метода `onCreate()`, например, при программном нажатии на `TextView`

Барабанная дробь... (не уверен, так как не пробовал)

**LIFEHACK**

В xml в тэг `TextView` добавьте

```
android:clickable = "true"
```

Когда вам надо получить высоту `TextView` (продумайте логику так, чтобы этот метод вызвался **не в onCreate()**), нажимайте программно на него

```
 textView.performClick();
```

Слушатель в `onCreate()`

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView tv = ((TextView)v);
        float height = tv.getHeight();
    }
}
```

P.S
Все же попробуйте вызвать `performClick` в `onCreate()`. Я думаю, что `View` который приходит в метод должен знать свою высоту

P.S.S
Повторюсь, способ не проверенный